# Ambigous column name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Ok so.. i can't really find a problem so i am posting here. P.S. I am new to MSSQL so please be gentle xD

I am getting Ambiguous Column name "Name"

I have two tables: Cardiology and Cardio_Schedule. I am wanting to select some columns from both and show them as a result in a gridview. I have made a query.. This is what it is:

```
string str = @"
SELECT Cardiology.CID,
       Cardiology.Name,
       Cardiology.Designation,
       Cardiology.Qualification,
       Cardiology.Shift,
       Cardiology.Appointment_Timings,
       Cardio_schedule.Ward_rounds,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot1,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot2,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot3,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot4,
       Cardio_schedule.BreakTime,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot5,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot6,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot7,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot8
FROM   Cardiology
       CROSS JOIN Cardio_schedule
WHERE  Cardiology.Name = Cardio_schedule.Name
       AND Name = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            con.Close();
```

IDK what the problem is. 
I did try it with ON but then it said incorrect syntax near 'ON'. Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Add a `TheTableName.` qualifier to`Name` in `AND Name = '"` just like in the `SELECT` list.

Comment: You should parametrize this, put a `'` in `TextBox1.Text` and see what happens when you run the query

Comment: Also use `INNER JOIN ... ON` rather than `CROSS JOIN ... WHERE`. Same semantics but more immediately understandable.

Comment: If you want to be really scared, put `' --` in  your textbox and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you so much @AlexK. Can you please put it as a proper answer so that i can select it to be the answer? thanks again!

Comment: Thanks guys. I will edit it and make it better! plus it might sound real stupid and dumb... but i don't know how to parametrize this. I have used parametrized queries but for add/edit/delete. Dunno how to do it for SELECT query.

Comment: @RahulSingh answered it fully

Comment: Obligatory link...http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is in the filter:-

```
AND Name = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
```

Change it with respect to the table you wanna refer:-

```
AND Cardiology.Name = '" + TextBox1.Text + "'";
            cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
```

Please Note your query is open for [SQL Injection attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection,), so you should use parametrized query instead like this:-

```
string str = "Cardiology.CID,Cardiology.Name, .....WHERE  
              Cardiology.Name = Cardio_schedule.Name
              AND Cardiology.Name = @Name";
cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name",DbType.NVarChar,20).Value = TextBox1.Text;
.....and so on
```

Please note here I have considered your datatype to be of NVarchar(20), you need to change that accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You missed at the end.

```sql
SELECT Cardiology.CID,
       Cardiology.NAME,
       Cardiology.Designation,
       Cardiology.Qualification,
       Cardiology.Shift,
       Cardiology.Appointment_Timings,
       Cardio_schedule.Ward_rounds,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot1,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot2,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot3,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot4,
       Cardio_schedule.BreakTime,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot5,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot6,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot7,
       Cardio_schedule.Slot8
FROM   Cardiology
       CROSS JOIN Cardio_schedule
WHERE  Cardiology.NAME = Cardio_schedule.NAME
       AND Cardiology.NAME = 'as'  -- `Cardiology` alias Missed
```

Answer (score 0):

At the end of your query there should be:

```
WHERE Cardiology.Name = Cardio_schedule.Name AND Cardio_schedule.Name = '"
```

or

```
WHERE Cardiology.Name = Cardio_schedule.Name AND Cardiology.Name = '"
```

Only writing Name property makes it ambiguous.